# ResourceNotFoundException on inflating menu

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

I'm trying to implement searchview, following the documentation I've added the options_menu.xml to my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" name="options_menu">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:title="@string/search_title"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
            android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
    </menu>
</resources>
```

And I try to Inflate the menu in my MainActivity.kt:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu)
    return true
}
```

But I get the following error when I run the program:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kotlinexp, PID: 27607
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File    from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f0c0000
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:990)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2096)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1111)
    at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:108)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:120)
    at com.kotlinexp.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.kt:64)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3142)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:325)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2830)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:455)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:56)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:   
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:519)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:975)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2096) 
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1111) 
    at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:108) 
    at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:120) 
    at com.kotlinexp.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.kt:64) 
    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3142) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:325) 
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2830) 
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:455) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:56) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

My activity_main.xml is as follows:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Surface"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showNotifBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:text="Show Notification"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showLocationBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Location"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/showNotifBtn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.614"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locationText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/showLocationBtn" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

I'm simply following the documentation don't know whats wrong, the error code doesn't specify what resource I'm missing. Help.

Comment: on which folder options_menu.xml have you added ?

Comment: Its under the values folder along with colors.xml, strings.xml etc.

Comment: you have to create ``menu`` folder under ``res`` directory and then place your file into the menu folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `options_menu` should be created under `res -> menu` and be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Doing this gives me the following error: `AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_search (aka com.kotlinexp:drawable/ic_search) not found.`
`

Comment: You should to put an icon with this name in your `drawable` folder or any icon you want but make sure to change it's name check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup)